# how to get current slide index: uib carousel

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, carousel

I would like to get the current slide index `onChange` and not `onClick` but I don't know how do do that.

First, I had it with ng-click, like this:

In the .html:

```
<ul uib-carousel id="myCarousel" active="active" no-wrap="noWrapSlides"
        style="background-color: #0a0a0a; height:100%; width:100%; padding: 0">
        <li id="mySlides" uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id"
            style="background-color: #0a0a0a; height: 100%;width: 100%;">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.imageUrl}}" ng-click="setSelectedImage(slide.data)" style="background-color: #0a0a0a; height: 100%;width: 100%; max-height: 640px; max-width: 800px"/>

        </li>
    </ul>
```

And in the .js:

```
 $scope.myInterval = 5000;
 $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
 $scope.active = 0;
 var currIndex = 0;
 var slides = $scope.slides = [];

 $scope.addSlide = function(media,data) {
      slides.push({
          imageUrl: $scope.urlWsImg+media.mediaId+"/stream/800",
          id: currIndex++,
          data:data
      });
 };

 $scope.addSlide($scope.currentImage.media,$scope.currentImage);//bootstrap
 for(var i=0;i<enrichedImages.length;i++) {
    var enrichedImage=enrichedImages[i];
    $scope.addSlide(enrichedImage.previewImage,enrichedImage);
 }
 $scope.setSelectedImage =function(imageUrl){
     $scope.currentEnrichedImage=imageUrl;
 }
```

I've tried on put an `onchange="setSelectedImage(slide.data)"` in `#my-carousel`, but it doesn't work since the slide is unknown when the change occurs.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `ngChange` because the directive doesn't expose any `ngModel`

From the [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) docs

> Note, this directive requires ngModel to be present.

But you have the `active` property that you can `$watch`

```
$scope.$watch('active', function(newIndex, oldIndex) {
    if (Number.isFinite(newIndex) && newIndex!==oldIndex) {
        // invoke your function here
    }
});
```

[Here is a forked plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/xj7LC6aq3XRmRirk9IO0?p=preview)

Comment: I have implemented same as your example. but I never get the $watch called when slide change. I have open the screen in modal view.

Comment: you should ask a new question and show your attempt

Comment: Can you please look into this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622483/i-want-to-know-the-current-slide-index-on-uib-carosal

Answer (score 1):

It seems that active is holding the current index.
You should be able to just use $scope.active.